# IE - removing cookies CookieConrol

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I am trying to remove a cookie from IE when the page loads.

The Cookie is no longer in use and needs to be removed, I have tried setting the expiry date as follows:

```
function seta() {    
  document.cookie = "CookieControl=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC";
}

function deleteCookie(name) {
  setCookie('CookieControl', "", {
    'max-age': -1
  })
}
```

If I create the cookie I can delete it.

```
$j1.cookie('CookieControl', 'hrd', { expires: 365, path: '/' });)
```

How do I delete an existing cookie in IE 11?

Comment: when are you calling those functions?

Comment: is it an http-only cookie?

Comment: @DanielA.White No http-only is false, the are being called on load. I am starting think it is a IE security setting